# Why do we use a simple average for pricing options in MonteCarlo?

Tags: options, monte-carlo

I was recently reviewing my notes on the Binomial Trees and MonteCarlo (MC) methods for option pricing. I've taken this for granted and just used the method....but I started questioning why we take a simple average for calculating the option value.
I understand that we're drawing independent random samples from the normal distribution....but isn't the prob of drawing say 0.65 different from drawing 1.465 (etc.)? If so, why don't we do a probability weighted expectation (like in the Binomial Tree) instead of the simple/equally weighted expectation in MC? Would appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about taking a probability-weighted average instead of equal-weighted? There is no need for that because naturally a simulated stochastic process will end up more in the regions that is represented by the risk-neutral distribution (mean rather than the tails for a normal distribution for example). Therefore, taking an equal-weighted average "already accounts for the probability-weighting part".

Comment: Yes. Each trajectory was simulated with the (log)normal distribution, and so it is OK to give each trajectory equal weighting in the final result. You basically have N draws from the (log)normal distribution so you can just average them, each is an equally valid representaion of what a (log)normal draw looks like.

Comment: Thanks  both! - what's a good book (or lecture not etc) to delve more into this? I checked Hull.....there's not much discussion of this idea...just the presentation of the method.

Comment: @Chet you can take a look at Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering by Paul Glasserman. Hull is very good but he does not go much into Monte Carlo.

Answer (score 0):

What weighted distribution would you choose? Besides, in situations where an analytical solution is not available, we don't know the distribution of the process, only the distribution of the white noise. If you already know the distribution of the process, you wouldn't bother with a Monte-Carlo simulation - it's computationally expensive.

The cool thing about MC is it's "always correct" (in the sense of the parameters you gave it). If you assume some distribution to correct the output, you will be more wrong than the results of the simulation.